# Woocommerce : How to add a custom meta_key to checkout billing_phone?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, meta-key

I want to enter the value of `digits_phone` meta key to be entered as `billing_phone` for every woocommerce order.

I came up with something like this but it did not work :

```
//Automatically add the digits phone number of the user, to woocommerce orders for every order

add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_posted_data', 'dg_manipulate_checkout_posted_data');
function dg_manipulate_checkout_posted_data ($data) {
    $data['billing_phone'] =['digits_phone'];

    return $data;
}
```

can anyone please help me to figure this out?

Comment: Hi, :) where are you getting digits_phone from ? assuming you're using a plugin to manage digits numbers, I guess you should be able to get the data with a call to `get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'digits_phone' , true );` ...

Comment: Hi @giulp. yes digits_phone is managed by the digits plugin. so how should I edit the code to actually get `digits_phone` from user meta and put it to `billing_phone` of woocommerce order? does it have to be something like this? `add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_posted_data', 'dg_manipulate_checkout_posted_data');
function dg_manipulate_checkout_posted_data ($data) {
    $data['billing_phone'] = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'digits_phone' , true );;

    return $data;
}`

Comment: You need to get current user data with `$current_user = wp_get_current_user();`

Comment: thanks for your help. actually I'm a newbie and dont really know how to use these codes altogether. can you please somehow combine the code that you sent, with the initial code that I asked in this question as an answer or correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I have never used the plugin myself, take this as a guideline

  *THIS CODE IS NOT TESTED !*
- Maybe this question is a better fit for [wordpress.stackexchange.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

From the last comment of [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/392453/woocommerce-how-to-automatically-input-digits-phone-number-filed-to-woocomme) I see that there should be 2 user metadata related to some *digits_phone*: 'digits_phone' and 'digits_phone_no'

Assuming that the one we want is `digits_phone`, this code should be a hint in the right direction:

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_posted_data', 'dg_manipulate_checkout_posted_data'); 

function dg_manipulate_checkout_posted_data ($data) {
  // save current user data in variable $current_user
  $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

  //get digits phone from db and save in variable $digits_phone
  $digits_phone = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'digits_phone' , true );     

  // assign to POSTed array and return it
  $data['billing_phone'] = $digits_phone;
  return $data; 
}
```

Also have a look at [How can I convert woocommerce checkout fields in capital letters](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/352781/how-can-i-convert-woocommerce-checkout-fields-in-capital-letters) to get a better picture of manipulating POST data

Comment: it worked for this purpose. thanks for your help. really appreciated